# authentication method 10 not supported PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, navicat

Can anyone explain why I can't create new connection postgres in navicat? It is possible that the error comes from version of navicat and Postgres? the error says:

> authentication method 10 not supported

I tried reinstalling my Postgres but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: You are using an outdated Postgres client library with navicat

Comment: What versions of Postgres and Navicat?

Comment: @Adrian Klaver The version of my navicat is 9.1 and the version of my postgres is 13.1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Do you know what postgres version should I install that compatible to navicat 9.1?

Comment: Guessing that authentication method 10 is `CRAM` (introduced in Postgres 10) I'm going to say you need Navicat 12.0.21 or greater. See here [Release Notes](https://navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-postgresql-release-note#L). Note: these are the Linux notes, for others see selector at top of page.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver  It works now I just installed and used navicat 12 and postgre version 11

Answer (score 4):

change the `pg_hba.conf` about flowing content:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                           trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Comment: This does not work on v15 of Postgres

Answer (score -1):

Funciona para Postgres 14

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                           trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```